# What is the media-key command in 14.04 for sound and brightness?

Tags: 14.04, laptop, media, i3-wm

I am using a laptop and with vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 I was able to control my monitor brightness with super+F5/F6.

Now I want to switch to i3wm and I need to manually bind those keys. What is the command to control the brightness/sound etc?

Answer (score 2):

For sound, the basic keys are:

- XF86AudioNext
- XF86AudioPause
- XF86AudioPlay
- XF86AudioPrev
- XF86AudioLowerVolume
- XF86AudioRaiseVolume
- XF86AudioStop

You can link them to you favorite music player, for example, setting XF86AudioNext to execute `gmusicbrowser -cmd NextSong`. The specific code will depend on the options allowed by your particular music player (which you can check in a terminal writing `"my_music_player" --help` or alike).

See [this link](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/XF86_keyboard_symbols) for a list of all available XF86 commands.